# Whatever I do Texifier does not create the PDF file

Tags: pdf

Whatever I do it keeps returning the message "PDF does not exist, please typeset your document to generate PDF"
Even when I typeset the document (no errors) the message stays the same and the PDF does not get generated.

[image]

This only happens when I use an external typessetter because the Live one is not available

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Check if the intermediate folder .texpadtmp contains some log file. Or if you an external tex system installed you can simply compile once in a normal editor and check if you get an error.